# Badges earned are shown in the achievements with the current site's badge symbol

Tags: bug, badges, notifications, top-bar, achievements-dialog

On the achievement screen, badge award notifications use the badge symbol of the site you're currently viewing, not the one you earned the badge on.

This is confusing because, for example, [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/badges) has a distinctive badge symbol that makes me think I earned a badge there at first glance, even though the site icon is from another site. The expected behavior is to take each badge symbol from the relevant site.